# Convert a pyodbc.Row to a string

Tags: python, pyodbc

I need to convert a pyodbc.Row to a string. The internet provides several suggestions, none of which seem to work for me.

```
row = cursor.fetchone() 
#unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', row).encode('ascii','ignore') #TypeError: must be unicode, not pyodbc.Row
#row.fieldname.encode('utf8') #AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'fieldname'
tblName = str(row)
tblName.replace("text:u","").replace("'","")
tblName = tblName.encode('utf-8')
print tblName
```

The above either give an error (shown in comment) or seems to have no effect as shown in the output here:

```
(u'myTableName', ) # print tblName
```

SQL is

```
tablesWithId = "select table_name \
                          from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS \
                          where COLUMN_NAME like 'MyId' "
cursor.execute(tablesWithId)
```

Python 2.7

Comment: I could be mistaken, but it almost looks like you just want the value of a field.  Did you try just `row.whatever_column_you_selected`?

Comment: You may be correct. How do I determine what `whatever_column_you_selected` is? Code complete doesn't do anything and I tried the name of the column from the query, but it says the `pyodbc.Row object has no attribute`

Comment: What was your sql select statement?

Comment: Added above. I tried `row.MyId` and get the no attribute error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your sql, I think you just want:

```
row.table_name
```

"`table_name`" is the name of the column you're selecting, and pyodbc makes each column a convenient attribute of the row object.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question of how to convert a pyodbc.row into a string.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question , it just selects the string