# How do you convert a list/pyodbc.row to a string in python so that str.replace can be used?

Tags: python, pyodbc

So without me cluttering up this question with code, imagine I have taken data from the database and stored a list of data in a variable "row".

```
print(row)
> ('29.99')
```

Now when I do, for example this:

```
newprice = row.replace("(","")
```

It brings up

> AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Row' object has no attribute 'replace'

How would I go about converting this to a string/integer so that I can perform calculations with it without the brackets or apostrophes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a pyodbc.Row to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832954/convert-a-pyodbc-row-to-a-string)

Comment: Technically it is a dupe but the answer there does not answer this question so I'm voting to keep it open.

Answer (score 4):

The returned row you are printing is a `pyodbc.Row` object, similar to a Python tuple, with all values returned by the query. For the first element in the `pyodbc.Row`, try `print(row[0])`.

If you had more than one value returned in the row, it might appear as:

```
>>> print(row)
('29.99', '19.99', '0.99')
```

Then these values could be addressed as `row[0]`, `row[1]`, and `row[2]`.

Comment: Note that as the error message indicates, `row` is not a Python tuple, it is a `pyodbc.Row` object. They are similar but not the same thing, and people sometimes run into difficulties when they think they're working with tuples but actually they aren't.

Comment: Good catch, I've amended the answer. Thanks.